# ida pro: dwarf fatal error; the dwarf plugin will stop now

Tags: ida

I recently observed this bug (error), when I upgraded gcc/g++ from version 9.x to 11.x.

[image]

Basically, Ida fails to parse debug information. I don't get this error when I compile with gcc 9.x. Note that, I get this error when I compile any kind (not specific to source code) of code with `-g` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that IDA pro fails to render dwarf5 format which seems to be default in gcc-11.

More info on that: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC-11-DWARF-5-Possible-Default

I changed the format to dwarf4 and it renders the data correctly.

```
g++ -gdwarf-4 example.cpp -o example.exe
```